# Android Studio - can't create Android virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 running Android Studio. I'm trying to run my code using the emulator, which requires first creating an Android virtual device, e.g. the default Nexus 7 or Nexus 5. My SDK path is `/opt/android-sdk-linux`.

This is the error message I'm getting while trying to install the requested components:

```
Loading SDK information...
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86-android-wear-19'Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86-android-tv-19'
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4' which was not installed.
  Done. Nothing was installed.

Install Failed. Please check your network connection and try again. You may continue creating your project, but it will not compile correctly without the missing components.
```

I can't figure it out - what's wrong with my network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up SDK manager. In windows it is android.bat that you open, not sure on Linux. Windows path is in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools, you may have to open as administrator. When the file opens a list of downloads appears. Download the appropriate files. Example android 4.4.2 (API) and all of the files under it when the list is expanded. I downloaded all of the API file versions so if I need them later.